# bash get names options in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopt

I want to invoke my bash shell script like so:

```
./myscript --dbName mydb --dbUser root --dbPass rootpass
```

How can i easily retrieve these in the script?

getopt looks like it will only work for single character options

Comment: Really?  When I type `man getopt` on Linux I see a `--longoptions` argument.  Strange that you don't.

Comment: @SeanBright No need to be sarcastic, lets all strive to make SO a friendly place even though the OP didn't do his homework...

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic.  I find it odd that his version doesn't support it.

Comment: Perhaps @marty is confusing getopt with getopts, which only takes single char option names

Comment: @SeanBright - my humble apologies, I read something into your comment that wasn't there.